# could not find library 'radial' in directories ['lib']...LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'radial.lib'

Tags: python, fortran, visual-studio-2019, intel-parallel-studio

I have some codes in `Python 3.7` mixed with `Fortran FOR` . I use Visual Studio 2019 and Intel Parallel Studio 2019 integrated.so when I run in Intel CMD `python setup.py install` I got this error :

```
could not find library 'radial' in directories ['lib']...
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'radial.lib'
error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe...
… failed with exit status 1181
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**setup.py:**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# Last Change: Sun Dec 19 11:00 AM 2010 J

# Copyright (C) 2008 Alexander Vinokurov <alexander.a.vinokurov@gmail.com>

descr   = """ScattPy package.

ScattPy provides numerical methods for solving light scattering problem
by non-spherical particles.
"""

import os
import sys

DISTNAME            = 'scikits.scattpy'
DESCRIPTION         = 'Light Scattering methods for Python'
LONG_DESCRIPTION    = descr
MAINTAINER          = 'Alexander Vinokurov'
MAINTAINER_EMAIL    = 'scattpy@googlegroups.com'
URL                 = 'http://scattpy.github.com'
LICENSE             = 'BSD'
VERSION             = '0.1.2'
DOWNLOAD_URL        = 'http://github.com/downloads/ScattPy/scikits.scattpy/scikits.scattpy-'+VERSION+'.tar.gz'

import setuptools
from numpy.distutils.core import setup

def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None, package_name=DISTNAME):
    if os.path.exists('MANIFEST'): os.remove('MANIFEST')

    from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
    config = Configuration(package_name, parent_package, top_path,
                           version = VERSION,
                           maintainer  = MAINTAINER,
                           maintainer_email = MAINTAINER_EMAIL,
                           description = DESCRIPTION,
                           license = LICENSE,
                           url = URL,
                           download_url = DOWNLOAD_URL,
                           long_description = LONG_DESCRIPTION)

    config.set_options(
        ignore_setup_xxx_py = True,
        assume_default_configuration = True,
        delegate_options_to_subpackages = True,
        quiet = True,
        )

#    config.add_subpackage("scikits")
#    config.add_data_files("scikits/__init__.py")

#    config.add_extension('f_utils',
#                         sources=[os.path.join('src', 'f_utils.for')]
#                         )

    config.add_extension('f_utils',
                         sources=[os.path.join('src', 'f_utils.for')]
                         )
    config.add_extension('f_spheroid',
                         sources=[os.path.join('src', 'sdmn.f')]
                         )

    config.add_extension('f_radial',
        sources=[os.path.join('src', 'radial.for')],
        library_dirs=["lib"],
        libraries=["radial"]
    )

    return config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(configuration = configuration,
        install_requires = 'numpy',
        namespace_packages = ['scikits'],
        packages = setuptools.find_packages(),
        include_package_data = True,
        #test_suite="tester", # for python setup.py test
        zip_safe = True, # the package can run out of an .egg file
        classifiers =
            [ 'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
              'Environment :: Console',
              'Intended Audience :: Developers',
              'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
              'Intended Audience :: Education',
              'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
              'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Mathematics',
              'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Physics',
              'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Astronomy', ])
```

**UPDATE #2:**

**my Intel CMD piece of codes:**

There were some command maybe make it working wrong,but now I don't have any idea:

`python setup.py install`

```
    ...

compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.228\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.228\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe /nologo /MD /nbs /names:lowercase /assume:underscore /O1
Fortran f90 compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.228\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.228\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe /nologo /MD /nbs /names:lowercase /assume:underscore /O1
Fortran fix compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.228\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.228\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe /nologo /MD /nbs /names:lowercase /assume:underscore /O1
compile options: '-Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\build\src.win-amd64-3.7\scikits\scattpy -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -c'
ifort.exe:f77: build\src.win-amd64-3.7\scikits\scattpy\f_radial-f2pywrappers.f
ifort.exe:f77: src\radial.for
ifort: command line warininfg #ort: co10161: unrecognized source type 'Files'; object file assumed
mmand line warning #ifort: command line warning #10161: unrecognized source type '(x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.228\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe'; object file assumed
10161: unifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '/c '
recognized source type 'Files'; object file assumed
ifort: command line warning #10161: unrecognized source type '(x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.228\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe'; object file assumed
ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '/c '
ifort: warning #10145: no action performed for file 'Files'
ifort: warning #10145: no action performed for file '(x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.228\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe'
ifort: warning #10145: no action performed for file 'Files'
ifort: warning #10145: no action performed for file '(x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.228\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe'
could not find library 'radial' in directories ['lib']
...
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'radial.lib'
...
failed with exit status 1181
```

**UPDATE #1:**

As I see there is a logical corresponding relations between `My Intel CMD` and `Setup.py` as below,So maybe adjusting the PATH solve the problem:

**`My Intel CMD` piece of code:**

**#1** `ifort.exe:f77: src\radial.for`

**#2** `could not find library 'radial' in directories ['lib']`

**with `setup.py`:**

**#1** `sources=[os.path.join('src', 'radial.for')],`

**#2** `library_dirs=["lib"],
        libraries=["radial"]`

**UPDATE #2 :**

As I used `MINGW gfortran` instead of `Intel Parallel Studio 2019` and used `Microsoft Visual Studio Build Tools 2019` instead of `Microsoft Vissual Studio 2019` and used `latest version of Python` , Do not Modifying `setup.py` and make some changes as UPADTE #1 and UPDATE #2 in [Some modification in `radial.for`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57150478/radial-o-error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbol-lambda-fatal-error-lnk1120) ,My problem Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I used `MINGW gfortran` instead of `Intel Parallel Studio 2019` and used `Microsoft Visual Studio Build Tools 2019` instead of `Microsoft Vissual Studio 2019` and used `latest version of Python` , Do not Modifying `setup.py` and make some changes as UPADTE #1 and UPDATE #2 in [Some modification in `radial.for`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57150478/radial-o-error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbol-lambda-fatal-error-lnk1120) ,My problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the actual ifort command that was executed. The output you labeled "my Intel CMD" (which it is not) indicates that a path on the ifort command line included a space `Program Files (x86)` but wasn't properly quoted. This prevented your source from being compiled. It looks to me as if the python script is getting this wrong. Curiously it is invoking the compiler but also placing the path to the compiler on the command line as if it were a source file.

You will need to dig in to the (not shown here) script and determine why it is constructing a bad command line.

Comment: critically what should I do? that was so confusing.

Comment: In `UPDATE #1` I found some corresponding relations between the script and the output.So maybe adjusting the PATH solve the problem

Comment: I can't tell you what you should do because I don't have the information of what the script looks like. I did tell you what went wrong - the script created a malformed ifort command line. You need to put some effort into figuring out why. If nothing else it would help to see the actual ifort command line issued. PATH is unlikely to be involved. Your Update 1 just reflects symptoms of the original problem I described above.

Comment: {SOLVED] @Steve Lionel  add `UPDATE #2` to your answer, So it would be the correct answer.